# View Page is not rendering in Thymeleaf and Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I've written my front end on thymeleaf and backend is in springboot and I've my this view page https://i.imgur.com/qOHWi4E.png and I am applying a search feature on it, and when I search the element and filter the record, I want, it should open on the same page but view name changed like something like this https://i.imgur.com/EUyB3zf.png

This is my default controller to load the list of registered user here:

```
@GetMapping("/registeredUsers/{page}")
public String registeredUsers(Model model, @PathVariable("page") Integer page) {
    model.addAttribute("title", "Registered User");
    
//  PageRequest pageable =PageRequest.of(page, perPageResultCount);
    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page, perPageResultCount);
    int totalNumberOfRegisteredUser = this.userRepository.findAll().size();
    Page<Users> listOfUserDetails = this.userRepository.findAll(pageable);
    
    List<Users> listOfUsers = listOfUserDetails.getContent();
    
    model.addAttribute("totalNumberOfRegisteredUser", totalNumberOfRegisteredUser);
    model.addAttribute("totalPage", listOfUserDetails);
    model.addAttribute("detailsOfTotalRegisteredUsers", listOfUsers);
    model.addAttribute("registeredUserClass", "active");
    
    model.addAttribute("currentPage", page);
    model.addAttribute("totalPages", listOfUserDetails.getTotalPages());
    //model.addAttribute("queryParameter", queryParameter);
    
    return "/admin/registeredUsers";
}
```

This is my search controller

```
@GetMapping("/searchKeyword/{page}")
public String searchKeyword(@RequestParam("keyword") String keyword, Model model, @PathVariable("page") Integer page) {
    model.addAttribute("pageNum", page);
    List<Users> listOfUsers = this.userRepository.searchByKeyword(keyword);
    model.addAttribute("detailsOfTotalRegisteredUsers", listOfUsers);
    return "/admin/registeredUsers";
}
```

As you can see in the search controller when I am returning the same page as **/admin/registeredUsers** from method  @GetMapping("/searchKeyword/{page}") which I am returning in **@GetMapping("/registeredUsers/{page}")**, it is changing the url bar and therefore, it is not rending the page and giving 404 error because there is no any page like **/admin/searchKeyword/0**

Answer (score 0):

> Solution

Just provide a custom error page and define the control logic to redirect when project detect something illegal like 0 or else.

> Issue

The major issue in your code snippet is that your prodide uri without any parameter , so that the http handler `/registeredUsers/{page}` which your define variables like `Integer page`  will be a default value  zero ,  If you use int instead of it and then appearently you will get an Nullpointexception error .